# database table updation based on some specific task

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-delete

I have a database table product

```
Prod_id Prod_name
1   Pen
2   Pencil
3   Eraser
4   book
```

When I delete product with `id =2`, the ids of *product 3 and 4 should decrement by 1* i.e. now it should be 2 and 3 as shown below

```
Prod_id Prod_name
1   Pen
2   Eraser
3   book
```

Any ideas to resolve this problem ..??
 I am using mySql.

Comment: Why do you want to do a silly thing like that? Just do a request with `ORDER BY id ASC` and use the row number as your *required number*.

Comment: when i delete some specific record , i want to update remaining records id in database, and this id is not a primary key.

Comment: if i delete pen....now the pencil id should be 1 similarly ids of remaining eraser and book should decrements ie it should be 2 and 3 respectively

Comment: It's never a good practise to do that. As everyone also said, use row number for that: `SET @row=0; SELECT @row := @row+1 Prod_name AS row, Prod_id, Prod_name FROM product;` No matter what the Prod_id is, the *row* will give you the numbers you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you REALLY need it

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92df2/1)

```
update product,
(select Prod_id,@row:=@Row+1 as rn 
   from product,(select @row:=0) tm 
 order by Prod_id) t1
set product.Prod_id=t1.rn
where product.Prod_id=t1.Prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that? If it is a `PRIMARY KEY`, leave it as is. But anyway, to answer your question, I suggest taht you create a stored procedure for that,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteItem(IN _id INT)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM product WHERE Prod_ID = _id;

    UPDATE  product a
            INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT  @row:=@row+1 NewID,
                        Prod_Name,
                        Prod_ID
                FROM    product a, (SELECT @row:=0) b
                ORDER   BY Prod_ID ASC
            ) c ON a.Prod_Name = c.Prod_Name
    SET     a.Prod_ID = c.NewID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ca6/2)

To call procedure,

```
CALL DeleteItem(3);
```

For faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `Prod_Name`.

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD INDEX (Prod_Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leave your `prod_id`s as they are and generate on the fly a new column with your numbering:

```
SET @row=0; 

SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, 
       * 
FROM   product 
ORDER  BY prod_id
```